# How can i concatenate and make a group of text in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

I have a table **tb1**. I want concatenated result set.

[image]

Please help me by writing  a query for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try this one,

```
SELECT  a.dept_id, 
        NewTable.NameValues
FROM    (
          SELECT DISTINCT dept_ID
          FROM tableA
        ) a 
        LEFT JOIN
        (
          SELECT  dept_id,
                STUFF((
                  SELECT  ', ' + [Name] 
                  FROM    tableA
                  WHERE   ( dept_id = Results.dept_id )
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS NameValues
          FROM    tableA Results
          GROUP BY dept_id
        ) NewTable
        on a.dept_id = NewTable.dept_id
GO
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d102/5)

HEre's another version

```
SELECT  a.dept_id, 
        SUBSTRING(d.nameList,1, LEN(d.nameList) - 1) ConcatenateNames
FROM 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT dept_id
            FROM   tableA
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT name + ', ' 
            FROM tableA AS B 
            WHERE A.dept_id = B.dept_id 
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) D (nameList)
GO
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d102/10)

Comment: Note that only the inner select is required on the first example (i.e. the table used for the left join)

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
select col1 + ' ' + col2 from bla.bla.bla
```

Comment: The values being concatenated are in different rows.