# one to many select in sql

Tags: sql, database

Well i have two tables first for employees and the second for emails, i want to see the employees with all his emails

```
table employees:
id | name  | idE
 1 | name1 | 1
 2 | name2 | 2
 3 | name3 | 3

table email:
id | idE | email
 1 | 1   | e1@email.com
 2 | 1   | e2@email.com
 3 | 2   | e@email2.com
 4 | 3   | e@email3.com
```

and i have this query:

```
select e.id, e.name, m.email from employees as e inner join email as m on p.idE = m.idE
```

and this is the result:

```
id | name  | email
 1 | name1 | e1@email.com
 1 | name1 | e2@email.com
 2 | name2 | e@email2.com
 3 | name3 | e@email3.com
```

i dont need employee 1 twice i just need both emails in the same row

Hi guys i modified my query to:
select em.name, 
STUFF(
(select  ',' + e.Email from tbl_Employees as m inner join tbl_Email as e on m.idE = e.idE for xml path(''))
,1,1,'') as emails
from tbl_employees as em

but now my problem is that i get this in each column of email:

e1@email.com,e2@email.com,e@email2.com,e@email3.com,

how can i do it to get only the emails of each employee?

instead of having every single email in each column

for example:

```
name | email
name1 | e1@email.com,e2@email.com,
name2 | e@email2.com,
name3 | e@email3.com,
```

pd: sorry if i have some mistakes im still learning english

Comment: Which database are you using?  Each has a different syntax for this, but you can look up the equivalent of `group_concat` for any database...

Comment: You can use `stuff` if you use `Sql Server`

Comment: also this is a fairly common answer you can search fro concatenate row values into string or something like that and you should find what you are looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display more than one value using a SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807451/display-more-than-one-value-using-a-sql-query)

Comment: im using sql  thank you very much for all the replys, im gonna see how stuff works  and gruop_concat

Comment: i have tried with select distinc like this 

select em.name, 
STUFF(
(select distinct ',' + e.Email from tbl_Employees as m inner join tbl_Email as e on m.idE = e.idE for xml path(''))
,1,1,'') as emails
from tbl_employees as em
but im still having the same result i have every single email in each column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my query after the changes

```
select em.name,
STUFF( 
  (select  ',' + e.Email from tbl_Employees as m inner join 
  tbl_Email as e on m.idE = e.idE 
  where em.idE = e.idE
  for xml path('')
) ,1,1,'') as emails 
from tbl_employees as em
```

and the results of this query

```
name | emails
name1 | e1@email.com,e2@email.com
name2 | e@email2.com
name3 | e@email3.com
```

thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 4):

Although what you're asking for is possible, and I'm sure you'll get several answers, your question is a good example of *be careful what you wish for* !  You're asking the DBMS to supply some presentation-level functionality.  You're usually better off letting SQL find the data you need, and handling presentation issues in your application.

`SELECT` returns a table of information, and the value of each column in a row is normally "atomic" in the sense that it holds a single value that SQL can compare to other values.  The tables in your database have the same property if they adhere to [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

One of the virtues of SQL is that "everything is a table": you can stack `SELECT`s one atop the other.

```
select * from (select a, b from T where a > b) as Z
```

Each inner one produces another table that the next outer one can act on.

Functions like `group_concat` (as an example) produce a non-atomic column.  It's only a short step from there to code like:

```
select * from ( select group_concat(a) as a_list from T ) as Z
where a_list like '%Henry%'
```

The programmer is forced into search strings instead of direct comparison.  The query becomes less precise and thus error-prone.

The fail-safe approach, in your example, is to read the results one by one from the DBMS, and concatenate a per-user address list by watching the `idE` column.  It will keep your query simpler, and if you later decide to present them another way, you can do that without diving into the database logic.

Comment: There are plenty of times I need to concatenate values, and while presentation layers are great for this things like Excel where a ton of SQL data ends up is not good at this particular function.